# Does Mongodb bindIp option accept dns name instead of ip with a port foward?

Tags: windows, mongodb, authentication, dns, bind

I have a structure like this:
[image]

I want to enable **B** to accept connection from **A**.
How can i configure it? I have this configuration in mongodb:

```
systemLog:
    destination: file
    path: C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\logs\mongod.log
storage:
    dbPath: D:\db
net:
    bindIp: 127.0.0.1,192.168.1.100, <can i mydomain1.com here??>
security:
    authorization: enabled
    keyFile: C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\keyfile-rs0.key
replication:
    replSetName: rs0
```

My firewalls are enabled in both of servers and router.

I think that's a bind name problem!

Somebody have a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this issue adding a rule in router mydomain1.com to get access from out side the net in a public port!